# Facebook SDK 4.2.1 - http 404 error, after permissions 'allow'

Tags: facebook, permissions, facebook-c#-sdk, http-status-code-404

I have small problem with http 404 error, after click on 'allow' on facebook permissions page.

When I type http://localhost:port address in browser, I get same error:

> cannot find /facebookredirect.axd/[app name]/default.aspx

After granting permissions (and after 404 error), when I want to use my app, I'm running it from my profile. Everything is fine and app works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem some time ago, I changed my web.config file, see the following:

I added this to the `httpHandlers` section in `system.web`:

```
<add verb="*" path="facebookredirect.axd" type="Facebook.Web.FacebookAppRedirectHttpHandler, Facebook.Web"/>
```

And added this to the `handlers` section in `system.webServer`:

```
<add name="facebookredirect" verb="*" path="facebookredirect.axd" type="Facebook.Web.FacebookAppRedirectHttpHandler, Facebook.Web"/>
```

And lastly I set the Url's in the codebehind (this should post back to the original app url and you'll see the variables added depends on what the user clicks):

```
CanvasAuthorizer cAuthorizer = new CanvasAuthorizer();
cAuthorizer.ReturnUrlPath = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("?allow=true");
cAuthorizer.CancelUrlPath = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("?allow=false");
```

Make sure you are setting your facebook settings in the config file, e.g:

```
<facebookSettings appId="0000000" appSecret="0000000000" canvasPage="http://apps.facebook.com/xxxxx/" canvasUrl="http://xxxxxxx" secureCanvasUrl="https://xxxxxxx"/>
```

I'm not 100% sure if I used the same SDK version, but give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your web.config file correctly. See the getting started documentation for instructions on how to do that: http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: Nope, its something different.

Comment: How to change 'next' parameter in auth string ? My string looks like http://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id=4444444443229&next=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A2548%2Ffacebookredirect.axd%2F%2FAPP_NAME%2Fdefault.aspx&display=page&cancel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F&locale=en_US&perms=user_likes&return_session=1&session_version=3&fbconnect=1&canvas=1&legacy_return=1&method=permissions.request

Comment: If it isn't that then it is something to do with your IIS config that is blocking the http handler request. Most likely because of the Default.aspx on the end of the url. You need to make sure that request is getting routed to the FacebookRedirectHttpHandler. The issue is not with the authentication process. If the user made it to the facebookredirect.axd url then they have already completed the authentication. You don't need to set the next parameter.